# Decomposition of a morphism into an epi- and a monomorphism

Tags: group-theory, functions

> Let $\varphi: G \to H$ be a homomorphism. Show that there exists an group $X$, an epimorphism $\psi:G \to X$ and monomorphism $\chi: X \to H$ such that $\varphi = \chi \circ \psi$.

#### The textbook approach

The first isomorphism theorem makes this easy enough.

Lets define $X$ as $G/\text{ker}(\varphi)$ and $\psi: G \to X; g \mapsto g\cdot \text{ker}(\varphi)$. Since $\psi$ is the canonical surjection it is clearly surjective. Then let $\chi: X \to H; g\cdot \text{ker}(\phi) \to g^\varphi$ which is by definition injective.

#### Why not?

But what is wrong with: Let $X = \text{im}(\varphi) \leq H$ then $\psi: G \to X; g\mapsto g^\varphi$ which is by definition surjective and by definition an morphism (since $\varphi$ is a morphism) and then let $\chi: X \to H; x\mapsto x$. the boring identity function. Which is an injective morphism as well.

Something must be wrong with the second approach, but I don't see what...
It guess it's something silly that I'm missing.

Comment: My inclination is the second, since it is way more natural.

Comment: Also, what book is this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong at all with your approach. The first isomorphism theorem just gives some extra information about how $X$ relates to $G$ and $\phi$.

Comment: @Randall In the course notes of a professor. Not in a published textbook :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches work and are equivalent:

The homomorphism $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism $\overline{\varphi} \colon G / \ker \varphi \to \operatorname{im} \varphi$, $\overline{g} \mapsto \varphi(g)$.
This isomorphism makes the following diagram commute:

[image]

(Here $\psi$ denotes the canonical projection, $\psi'$ the restriction of $\varphi$, $\chi$ the induced homomorphism $G / \ker \varphi \to H$, $\overline{g} \mapsto \varphi(g)$ and $\chi'$ the canonical inclusion.)
Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism it follows that $\psi$ is injective iff $\psi'$ is injective, and that $\chi$ is surjective iff $\chi'$ is surjective.